# Button element not working in IE JQuery/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a simple HTML button element that looks like this

< type='button' class='cancelButton' id='cancelMe' name='cancelMe' value='cancel' >

This calls JQuery and then AJAX

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$(".cancelButton").click(function() {
var cancelVals = "cancel=" + $(this).attr("value");
//RUN AJAX
  $.ajax({
    url: "save.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: cancelVals + "&page=" + currentPage + "&jobNum=" + jobNum,
    success: function (response) {alert(response);}
        });
     });
  });
```

I cannot get IE to return a response no matter what I do. I tried using a < button > element and even a submit button but no dice.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Is the issue with the button element itself, or maybe rather with your AJAX request? And what does the error console say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML will be

```
<input type='button' class='cancelButton' id='cancelMe' name='cancelMe' value='cancel'>
```

Did you define `currentPage  and jobNum` yet?

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#cancelMe', function(){
  var cancelVals = "cancel=" + $(this).attr("value");
  //RUN AJAX
  $.ajax({
    url: "save.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: cancelVals + "&page=" + currentPage + "&jobNum=" + jobNum,
    success: function (response) {alert(response);}
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes. I checked and they call correctly.  Even tried swapping them out for plain text for testing.

Comment: Looks like part of it was another Jquery library interfering with the request. Your post got me headed in the right direction so I marked it correct and hopefully it will help someone else dealing with the woes of IE.